# [Beginner] About running a package like a node

Tags: ros, package, node, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi i am stuck because of this, yesterday i ran the HelloWC (not following the name for files convention) and it works, today i try to recompile it and run.... but this is the ouput:

```
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/robot/Desktop/package_2/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/robot/Desktop/package_2/build"
####
[ 50%] Built target HelloWC
[100%] Built target HelloWC_node
robot@ASHROCK:~/Desktop/package_2$ rosrun HelloWC HelloWC_node
[rospack] Error: stack/package HelloWC not found
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named HelloWC_node below 
[rosrun] Found the following, but they're either not files,
[rosrun] or not executable:
[rosrun]   ./src/HelloWC_node
[rosrun]   ./devel/share/HelloWC_node
[rosrun]   ./devel/lib/HelloWC_node
[rosrun]   ./devel/lib/HelloWC_node/HelloWC_node
[rosrun]   ./build/HelloWC_node
[rosrun]   ./build/HelloWC_node/catkin_generated/stamps/HelloWC_node
robot@ASHROCK:~/Desktop/package_2$
```

Why is this going on?
(i ran the `source devel/setup.bash` and it remains equal)

Thanks before hand!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202427/%5Bbeginner%5D-about-running-a-package-like-a-node/) by [pexison](https://answers.ros.org/users/21144/pexison/) on ROS Answers with karma: 82 on 2015-02-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe your package is also named HelloWC_node, not just HelloWC.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pexison](https://answers.ros.org/users/21144/pexison/) on 2015-02-04**:
Thanks, `rosrun HelloWC_node HelloWC_node` solved the Problem, what a confusion of names, i will more carefull with this!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you copy your workspace to a usb-stick with NTFS file system or zip file and back? The executable file flags get lost during this....

To solve this the easiest would probably be to rebuild your entire workspace. But delete the build and devel folders before because otherwise, if you did not make changes to the src files the build files will not be recreated.

i. e.

- go to your workspace folder (the folder that contains src/ devel/ and build/ folders; where you called catkin_make)
- run `rm -r devel`
- run `rm -r build`
- run `catkin_make`
- run `rosrun HelloWC HelloWC_node`

and everthing should work again

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2015-02-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pexison](https://answers.ros.org/users/21144/pexison/) on 2015-02-04**:
Hi, no I just try to recompile yesterdays work, I already followed your instructions and the problem is half solved, now  get this:

```
robot@ASHROCK:~/Desktop/package_2$ rosrun HelloWC HelloWC_node
[rospack] Error: stack/package HelloWC not found
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-02-04**:
Have you remembered to `source devel/setup.bash` after running `catkin_make`?